# Get value of element once then keep that value static

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using

```
function expand(btn) {
var box = btn.parentNode.parentNode,
    ipsum = box.getElementsByTagName("p")[0],
    textSize = window.getComputedStyle(ipsum, null).getPropertyValue('font-size'),
    lineHeight = window.getComputedStyle(ipsum, null).getPropertyValue('line-height'),
    boxWidth = window.getComputedStyle(box, null).getPropertyValue('width'),
    initialHeight = window.getComputedStyle(box, null).getPropertyValue('height'),
    numText = parseInt(textSize),
    numWidth = parseInt(boxWidth),
    numHeight= parseInt(initialHeight);


if(box.style.height == "150px"){
    box.style.height = "40px";
    ipsum.style = "display:none";
}
else{
    box.style.height = "150px";
    ipsum.style = "display:inline";
}
console.log(lineHeight);
}
```

to get the initial height value of an element the only problem is that the element height changes frequently, but the first value obtained is always correct how can i get the initial value and keep it static? 
how do i only store the value in the variable once, i need it in a variable to do calculations but as the value keeps changing i am getting the wrong number outputs.

Comment: well, unless you keep storing the height value into that variable again and again, you have your initial value right there.. Maybe I'm missing something, could you elaborate on the problem (in your question please, not as a comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refactor the function to store the *initialHeight* in a "private" variable the first time it's run:

```
var expand = (function() {

    var initialHeight;

    // Return a function that holds initialHeight in a closure
    return function (btn) {

      // Get box before setting/getting initialHeight
      var box = btn.parentNode.parentNode;

      // Set initialHeight only if undefined
      initialHeight = initialHeight || window.getComputedStyle(box, null).getPropertyValue('height');

      // Do other variables
      var ipsum = box.getElementsByTagName("p")[0],
          textSize = window.getComputedStyle(ipsum, null).getPropertyValue('font-size'),
          lineHeight = window.getComputedStyle(ipsum, null).getPropertyValue('line-height'),
          boxWidth = window.getComputedStyle(box, null).getPropertyValue('width'),
          numText = parseInt(textSize),
          numWidth = parseInt(boxWidth),
          numHeight= parseInt(initialHeight);

      if(box.style.height == "150px"){
        box.style.height = "40px";
        ipsum.style.display = "none";

      } else {
        box.style.height = "150px";

        // If ipsum is a P, probably better to use "" (empty string) here
        // so it returns to its default or inherited value
        // ipsum.style.display = "inline";
        ipsum.style.display = "";
      }

      console.log(lineHeight);
    }
}());
```

The above is a proper refactoring, tested with the following markup:

```
<style type="text/css">
#box {border: 1px solid blue;}
#notBox {border: 1px solid red;}
#ipsum {border: 1px solid yellow;}
</style>
<div id="box">box
  <div id="notBox">notBox
    <input type="button" onclick="expand(this)" value="Expand&hellip;">
    <p id="ipsum">ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this method is returning TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle is not an object.

Comment: @Plentybinary—ok, I wrote some HTML and CSS to test it, just needed to move getting *box* before setting *initialHeight*.

Comment: @RobG i am having the same problem, after seeing your answer i defined my variable like this : current_date = current_date || this.get_current_UTCDate();     than it's returning 'current_date' is not defined. If i am removing || condition, than it is working properly

Comment: @RobG can you help me out with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701331/how-to-store-static-value-from-variable-that-keep-changes-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment41996458_26701331

Answer (score 1):

Can you set it as an attribute? Something like:

```
// set the value once some place
box.setAttribute('data-init-height', window.getComputedStyle(…)… );

// when setting the initial height, check for the attribute first
initialHeight = box.getAttribute('data-init-height') || window.getComputedStyle(…)…;
```

---

Follow-up:
[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fe7m9azu/2/)

Comment: when using this i am getting TypeError: Not enough arguments to Element.setAttribute referring to the box variable.

Comment: @Plentybinary see the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Each time you execute the function `expand`, you got a new value for initialHeight.
All that you need is to record it in a closure, with a hash if you're having more than 1 btn to handle, valued with arrays if you'd like to record multi heights for each btn. Just like this:

```
// predefine the function expand for furthre usage.
var expand;
(function() {
    /* 
    having arrays as value, indexed like this:
    {
        <btn_1_id> : [<firstHeight>, <2nd Height>, ...],
        <btn_2_id> : [],
        ...
    }
    */
    // Let's assume every btn is having an id. You may think another way yourself it they don't.
    var initialHeightForMultiBtns = {};
    expand = function(btn) {
        // ...blablabla
        initialHeightForMultiBtns[btn.id] = initialHeightForMultiBtns[btn.id] || [];
        initialHeightForMultiBtns[btn.id].push(window.getComputedStyle(box, null).getPropertyValue('height'));

        console.log(initialHeightForMultiBtns[btn.id][0]); // the real initialized height for the given btn.
        // ...blablabla
    }
})()

expand(btn_1); // let's expand btn_1 here.
```

Good luck.

Comment: no thats not it, the value still flips from 40 to 150

Comment: Sorry didn't see your updates.
I've answered it again, hope it's what you're looking for.

Comment: @yarmyarch— *initialHeight* isn't global, it's held in a closure and is "private".

Comment: this method throws refrenceError: expand is not defined

Comment: So you're using expand out of the closure? Sure it won't be a problem my friend. I've updated again.

Comment: getting btn is undefined with this method, i tried defining it under var initialHeight; but still no go.

Comment: I think btn should be a param of the function expand and shouldn't be defined anywhere else. try this when using expand: `expand(document.getElementById("HERE IS THE ID OF YOUR BTN"));`,
that's just because the btn isn't parsed into the function I think.

Comment: cant use that unfortunately because this needs to be applied to many elements, is there a way to maybe have each new value put into an array? that way array[0] would be the initial value and then i can have array[1] as the set value if i need to use it later?

Comment: Sure. See the new answer posted.